# Linux - set local time without permission

Tags: date-time

I log into a linux server, which is in an European time zone. How to make my account in an Asian time zone? And I don't have the super user permission.

The systems are centos 6.5 and ubuntu 12.10, two servers.

Comment: What distro are you using?

Comment: centos 6.5 and ubuntu 12.10, two servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have read permissions to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/` and its children (which you would normally), you can set the timezone in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`, by executing this command:

```
export TZ="/usr/share/zoneinfo/{TIMEZONE-DIRECTORY}/{TIMEZONE_FILE}"
```

with the correct Timezone dir and Timezone file within /usr/share/zoneinfo/.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-set-time-zone-per-user-basis/

Comment: this works, but I meet something really weird. It seems the server is set wrong. After I set `TZ` as `Asia/Shanghai`, and then call `date`, it gives me another wrong time. The real time is 13:22, but it shows 21:27.(before the setting, it shows 08:27)

Comment: did you close the shell and reopen it after making the change? that may help.

Comment: I did. the real time is 13:22, before close the shell it shows 08:27, after reopen the shell, it shows 21:27. Both are wrong. Is it a problem with the system?

Comment: well, nothing in that command can affect the server itself,so don't worry that you've broken anything for anyone else.  try running `export -p` to confirm that the TZ variable has been correctly set, and everything is spelled correctly. the server clock may be off. use `date -u` to check the UTC time, and verify it against http://www.worldtimeserver.com/current_time_in_UTC.aspx

Comment: `date -u` gives me right time, but `date` still not. does that mean the server clock is off? how to make it on?

Comment: no, that implies that the server clock is correct, which makes it extra weird that its off when we apply the TZ file. your TZ variable has the full path `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai` (or the same path in \usr\lib\... ), right? Try editing the file `~/.bashrc` and add the whole export command at the bottom of the file. save the file, exit the editor, logout and back in, and try again.

Comment: I find that without `TZ`, it is shown as `xx:xx:xx EST`, with `TZ`, it is shown as `xx:xx:xx CST`, and `date -u` will shown as `xx:xx:xx UTC`. And with/without `TZ`, the `date -u` will always show correct time.

Comment: Remember to EXPORT the TZ variable once it is set!  Otherwise, the setting will not propagate to other commands that you run.

Comment: @FrankThomas Sorry, I think I misunderstand your answer, the `date -u` doesn't give me a right time. It's not same as the link, I mistook that.. I said it's right, which really means it is almost the same as the time in Shanghai, more specific, it's 5 minutes faster than real time.

Comment: ok, that means your servers time is off. the date -u provides UTC time, which should match the URL. if not, then the servers system clock is off. the timezone file just tells your shell how much to adjust UTC for your location. it sounds like you will have to contact the server admin, and ask them to set the time as you need it, perhaps by synching with a NTP server, or by setting the correct Shangai time. Good luck.

Comment: @FrankThomas thank you so much, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the time zone by executing the below command.

> mv /etc/localtime /etc/localtime.bak
>
> ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/xxxx /etc/localtime

Replace Asia/xxxx according to your time zone.

Comment: "And I don't have the super user permission." yet you give him 2 commands that start with sudo.

Comment: those commands won't work correctly without admin, on most systems with default permissions on \etc\